# Regular expression to match 'R33' and 'r34E'

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that matches R33 and r34E. I tried `(R|r)[0-9]{2}+[A-Z]{1}` but got an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
/[rR][0-9]{2}[A-Z]?/
```

Comment: Thanks will follow up tom. to let u all know if it works

Comment: @Rob: Note that it probably doesn't want the slashes; they're convention in several languages that the expression is supposed to be a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

It is an invalid Regular Expression. If you want to have 2 or more digits, {2}+ won't work, you should use {2,}.

`(R|r)[0-9]{2,}[A-Z]?`

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9]{2}+
```

That plus sign looks wrong. If you take that out:

```
(R|r)[0-9]{2}[A-Z]?
```

Appears to do what you want (upper- or lowercase R, two digits, optionally any uppercase letter).

Comment: would ? restrain the last letter to one so that it only accept something like R22 or R23D

Comment: @Rob: The question mark means "0 or 1" - essentially, it might have the [A-Z] on the end, or it might not. When it comes to "not working", you'll need to go into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try `^(R|r)[0-9]{2}$|^(R|r)[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}$`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is invalid.

You can use `{2}` or `+` on an expression, but not both.